# Comparing Two UIColor DynamicProvider (iOS13) Returns False

Tags: swift, uicolor, xcode11, ios13, ios-darkmode

## Xcode 11 / iOS 13

When I initialize 2 UIColor objects using `UIColor(dynamicProvider:)` I cannot use `color1 == color2` anymore since (I think) it is not capable of comparing the closure.

This issue also breaks the comparison of NSAttributedStrings when you use colors in the attributes.

### Example

```swift
extension UIColor {

    // MARK: - Specify All Colors

    convenience init(light: UIColor, dark: UIColor) {

        self.init(dynamicProvider: { (traits) in
            switch traits.userInterfaceStyle {
            case .unspecified, .light: return light
            case .dark: return dark
            }
        })
    }
}

UIColor(light: .white, dark: .white) == UIColor(light: .white, dark: .white) // false
```

### Current (non-optimal solution)

```swift
func equals(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    guard let rhs = object as? UIColor else { return false }

    var lhsR: CGFloat = 0
    var lhsG: CGFloat = 0
    var lhsB: CGFloat = 0
    var lhsA: CGFloat = 0
    getRed(&lhsR, green: &lhsG, blue: &lhsB, alpha: &lhsA)

    var rhsR: CGFloat = 0
    var rhsG: CGFloat = 0
    var rhsB: CGFloat = 0
    var rhsA: CGFloat = 0
    rhs.getRed(&rhsR, green: &rhsG, blue: &rhsB, alpha: &rhsA)

    return  lhsR == rhsR && lhsG == rhsG && lhsB == rhsB && lhsA == rhsA
}
```

With this in place you cannot use `==` anymore but have to explicitly call this function when you want to compare colors.

But a much better solution would have to compare each representation of the color by using `resolvedColor(with:)`. But this would have to be implemented by Apple so we can continue using `==` nad the `Equatable` protocol.

Comment: Add the code that you've tried so far,

Comment: Done - thx for the hint.

Comment: Comparing dynamic colors from xcassets works as expected, but I don't know if you can use it.

Comment: Alternative is https://stackoverflow.com/a/58398769/1071510, but it won't work for `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: @Grubas no apparently not since we have al lot of white-labeled apps that reuse existing colors (like the text color) and therefore we have to create them in code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `===` instead of `==`

```
UIColor(light: .white, dark: .white) === UIColor(light: .white, dark: .white)
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me since I (and NSAttributedString) needs component-wise equality (==) not pointer-wise (===). The example `UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0) === UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0)` e.g. returns false already which means that using the dynamic provider will also not work in that case.