# How to compare two UIDynamicProviderColor?

Tags: swift, ios13

I'm comparing two `UIColor` initialised using the new iOS 13 `init(dynamicProvider:)`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/3238041-init

but that's what I get runtime when I compare them in unit test with an `XCTAssertEqual`:

```
XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(<UIDynamicProviderColor: {...}; 
provider = <__NSMallocBlock__: {...}>>)") is not equal to 
("Optional(<UIDynamicProviderColor: {...}; provider = <__NSMallocBlock__: {...}>>)")
```

This is an example of how I create the color:

```
struct Style {
    static var color: UIColor {
        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
                return UIColor { traitCollection in
                    return traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .secondarySystemBackground : UIColor.white
                }
        } else {
            return UIColor.white
        }
    }
}
```

The test code:

```
func testExample() {
    XCTAssertEqual(Style.color, Style.color)
}
```

I tried overriding `isEqual` method of `UIColor` with an extension but apparently it's not called.

Do you have any workaround for this?

Comment: What's the point of returning a dynamic color that only returns black no matter the current traits? That's not dynamic. Just return black.

Comment: Is that `return Color.black` line supposed to be `return UIColor.black`?

Comment: Update your question with the actual relevant test code so we can see how you actually perform the test, not just the result of the test.

Comment: @rmaddy thanks for the corrections, fixed the example code

Answer (score 10, accepted):

One solution to your unit test is by changing your code to this:

```
XCTAssertEqual(Style.color.cgColor, yourExpectedColor.cgColor)
```

In the iOS 13 at runtime it is comparing two UIDynamicProviderColor objects that return an UIColor object after running a block "(UITraitCollection) -> UIColor".
So, that's the reason you have two different objects. Getting the cgColor from both you can compare them correctly. I hope I was helpfull.

Comment: Thanks, Jhonathan! I would never have found this!

Comment: A better solution would be to call `resolvedColor(with:)` on the colors, passing in the trait collection. This will get you a non-dynamic color that suits the dark/light mode specified by the trait collection.

Answer (score 0):

Currently we do the following:

```swift
func equals(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
    guard let rhs = object as? UIColor else { return false }

    var lhsR: CGFloat = 0
    var lhsG: CGFloat = 0
    var lhsB: CGFloat = 0
    var lhsA: CGFloat = 0
    getRed(&lhsR, green: &lhsG, blue: &lhsB, alpha: &lhsA)

    var rhsR: CGFloat = 0
    var rhsG: CGFloat = 0
    var rhsB: CGFloat = 0
    var rhsA: CGFloat = 0
    rhs.getRed(&rhsR, green: &rhsG, blue: &rhsB, alpha: &rhsA)

    return  lhsR == rhsR && lhsG == rhsG && lhsB == rhsB && lhsA == rhsA
}
```

With this in place you cannot use `==` anymore but have to explicitly call this function when you want to compare colors.

But a much better solution would have to compare each representation of the color by using `resolvedColor(with:)`. But this would have to be implemented by Apple so we can continue using `==` nad the `Equatable` protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Following the suggestion by @adurdin you can check dark and light mode colors by doing something like this:

```
XCTAssertEqual(
    Style.color.resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .dark)), 
    .secondarySystemBackground
)
XCTAssertEqual(
    Style.color.resolvedColor(with: UITraitCollection(userInterfaceStyle: .light)),
    .white
)
```